# Outlook 2010 Folder Structure Search

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

I work at a helpdesk and today I received a call from a user who lost a folder in Outlook.
When I connected to the user's PC, I discovered that the user has several hundreds of folders. She had the same name folder in several different locations.

When we used *Advanced Find* we found the messages. It said that messages are located in folder *X*. The only problem was, we could not locate the folder *X* in the list.

Does anyone know of any way to quickly and easily browse all the folders or look up a folder in Outlook 2010?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For anyone who might happen to come across this question (I'm sure the original poster is long gone), the solution (under Windows 7, at least) is to use the Windows Search utility (the one available when you click the "Windows Orb" on your deskbar). You can search using the same terms that you searched outlook with, then filter your results to just Outlook items (by clicking on the section header "Microsoft Outlook" in the Windows Search results list). Select an item in the list and the Folder path (w/in Outlook) is in the status at the bottom of the window.  (You can also add "Path" to the list of columns in your Details display, which would allow you to sort the results list by the path).

Comment: Brilliant, thank you. I had the same problem with a folder which, it turns out, had been dragged into another folder at some distant past time. I have no idea why Outlook's own search facility is, how may I put it delicately... pathetic. There's absolutely no point in Advanced Find giving you the name of the folder without its parents, something which leaves you little the wiser about how to get to it.

Answer (score 1):

There is a helpful add-in located here: http://www.add-in-express.com/sample-outlook-addins/outlook-folder-path.php

The add-in allows you to view the folder location on any open message. So, if you had an email in your search results that you could not find, you can open the message and the folder location is listed at the bottom of the message. It is a link, so you can also click on it to go to the folder in the main Outlook window.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 1):

Once a message is found, open it.

CTRL+SHIFT+F to open another Advanced Find box.

You will note the folder containing the open message is shown in the "In:" box. Click on the Browse button to locate the folder.

Comment: This does work in Office 2013, not sure if it works in Office 2010, don't have that version to check any more.

Answer (score 0):

There's a Folder List option in the Go menu (at least it's there in Outlook 2007), isn't it what you are looking for?

Comment: Go Menu is no longer in 2010 unless i'm not seing it.